# Set http headers to requests generated by browser?

Tags: javascript, http, authentication, browser, http-headers

I have server with HTTP basic authentication and I have client script which knows username and password for above HTTP server. I use `XHR` request and it's `setRequestHeader` to set Authorization headers, this bit avoids browser from prompting default HTTP login dialog.

```
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authInfo);
```

This is normal *for AJAX requests*, but in case I want download file from mentioned server and I'm forced to go *without AJAX* and use something like `window.location.href` from JavaScript where browser creates request itself. Since this request will not include Authorization header (brwoser will add Authorization header for every request automatically only after it prompts login dialog and saves base64 of login info for actual server) browser will prompt HTTP login dialog, which I want to avoid.

So is there a way to set headers to *non-ajax* requests created by browser?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the username and password in the URL?

```
location.href = 'http://user:password@example.com/path/to/download';
```

I think that should work in most browsers except, unfortunately, [Internet Explorer 7+](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489).

Alternatively, if you have access to the server, you could put a script on the server side that uses cookies to authenticate. Cookies can be set with JavaScript.

Comment: Note that auth cookies may be abused for [CSRF attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. 

Unfortunately, I have no script interpreter on server-side so I cannot second way.

Comment: Just one note about first approach, is there a way to pass user:password for example encoded in base64 or something. 

I think this can be done by sending for example base64 encoded user and password in URL, decoding this string on server-side and redirecting on new URL with apache. Since this is download user will not see decoded URL in browsers address bar.

But I'm asking maybe there is a native way to do this.